# Windows Apache .htaccess RewriteRule error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

On my linux server i have following .htaccess:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ index.php?module1=page&module2=$1&$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^-]*)$ index.php?module1=page&module2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^game/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ index.php?module1=game&module2=$1&$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^game/([^-]*)$ index.php?module1=game&module2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ index.php?module1=admin&module2=$1&$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^-]*)$ index.php?module1=admin&module2=$1 [L]
```

Now i want to set it on my windows 7. I am using WebServ as server (it's build on top of apache2).

If i copy paste this .htaccess then it ends up in http error 500

I have to comment Options FollowSymlinks to make it work.
But rewriting is still not working at all.
I've tried:

- changing all

  AllowOverride xxx to AllowOverride All in apache2/conf/httpd.conf
- in the same file i have:

  LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so (without comment)

So the questions are:
1. Why Options FollowSymLinks ends in http error 500
2. Why rewriting dont work?

Best wishes

Comment: Symlinks do not exist on MS-Windows environments. They are a concept of the unix/linux tradition and have no immediate corresponding feature under MS-Windows. That probably means that the option does not exist in that http server if it is created especially for that environment.

Comment: We cannot say more since we do not have access to your system and all the information. You have to give it to us. That starts by: what _exactly_ do you actually mean by "But rewriting is still not working at all"? And _please_ add the relevant parts of your http servers error log file to the question.

Comment: "rewriting is still not working at all" beceause if i go to myurl/game/overview it says error 404 instead of rewriting it to index.php?module1=game&module2=$1&$2

Comment: So what about the contents of the error log file I asked for? Can't see that you added that to the question...

Comment: I solved it, `RewriteBase` did the job

Comment: Great to hear that! I suggest you post an answer yourself with that solution, _why_ that is required and works and how you found out about it. That way others can learn from you.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging is hard.  Debugging is so much harder when you don't have enough facts.  You need more facts.  Not imaginary facts, real ones.  To get more real facts, turn on logging.  If running Apache 2.4, [see this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging).  Do something like this:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

Go read the log and it will tell you in detail what Rewrite is doing.  If there's not enough detail, bump it up to `trace6`.  My experience is that 500's are often (not always) caused by infinite looping.  Good luck!

Comment: In my httpd.conf i have `LogLevel warn` if i change it to `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` my server doesnt want to start (it prints that LogLevel expects one argument). That beceause my apache version is 2.2

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, is it?

Comment: You mean that I sould upgrade apache to 2.4?